# OCaml type error with function application

Tags: function, ocaml, typeerror

```
let max2 (x:float) (y:float) :float = 
    if x>=y then x else y;;

let max4 (x:float) (y:float) (a:float) (b:float) :float =
    max2(max2(x, y), max2(a, b));;
```

> Error: This expression has type 'a * 'b but an expression was expected of type float

I was trying to get the max of 4 numbers using a max between 2 numbers function.

Comment: `let f x y` and `let f (x, y)` are different!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
let max2 (x:float) (y:float) :float = 
  if x >= y then x else y;;
    
let max4 (x:float) (y:float) (a:float) (b:float) :float =
  max2 (max2 x y) (max2 a b);;
```

the types for max2 and max4 are explicitly specified so the error should be resolved

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for applying a function `f` to some arguments `arg1` and `arg2` is simply:

`f arg1 arg2`

Notice the complete absence of parenthesis or commas to separate the arguments. If i want let's say to apply another function `g` to this previous result, i can now put parenthesis **around the function expression and the last argument** as in:

`g (f arg1 arg2)`

This is different from what you may be used to in other languages where you put parenthesis after the function name and around the arguments.

Also, the syntax `(e1,e2)` builds the couple (2-tuple) with `e1` as first member and `e2` the second.

So `max2 (x, y)` is the application of the function `max2` to a *single* argument which is a couple. This is different than `max2 x y` which is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Addendum to [@ghilesZ's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75296740/15261315): local bindings can also be useful.

```ml
let max2 (x:float) (y:float) : float = 
  if x >= y then x 
  else y

let max4 (x:float) (y:float) (a:float) (b:float) : float =
  max2 (max2 x y) (max2 a b)
```

We could write:

```ml
let max4 (x:float) (y:float) (a:float) (b:float) : float =
  let m1 = max2 x y in
  let m2 = max2 a b in
  max2 m1 m2
```

*Also*, because the types for `max2`'s arguments are explicitly specified, we can elide the return type annotation, and *all* type annotations on `max4` and OCaml will correctly infer the types.

```ml
let max2 (x:float) (y:float) = 
  if x >= y then x 
  else y

let max4 x y a b =
  let m1 = max2 x y in
  let m2 = max2 a b in
  max2 m1 m2
```

You may also wish to generalize this to work on a list of floats, which you could implement `max4` in terms of.

```ml
let maxA =
  function
  | [] -> failwith "Empty list"
  | h::t -> List.fold_left max2 h t

let max4 x y a b = 
  maxA [x; y; a; b]
```